# How to retrieve SSL certificate of an IIS website in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis

I'm trying to retrieve the certificate of a bunch of IIS websites and match the thumbprint with a certificate that I have. If the thumbprint is matched, that's perfectly fine. However, if the thumbprint is not matched then I want to add that specific certificate to that website. I know I can verify if the desired certificate exists using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object Thumbprint
```

And I can get the IIS websites and look at bindings using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:Sites | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Bindings
```

However, I can't figure out how I can retrieve the certificate thumbprint of these websites. I have the target certificate's thumbprint stored in a variable like so:

```
$CertThumbprint = "###############################"
```

If I am going at it the wrong way, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, this is not my code, found that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8kwke8/how_do_you_match_iis_sites_with_iis_site_ssl/dzb56qx?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
You can try this perhaps:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$siteThumbs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Site       = $_.Sites.Value
        Thumbprint = $_.Thumbprint
    } 
}
```

This should give you an array of objects with both the sites and the thumbprints for you to compare.

---

From your comment, I gather more than one site can share the same thumbprint and to list them separately, you could do this (untested)

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$siteThumbs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | Foreach-Object {
    $thumb = $_.Thumbprint
    foreach ($site in $_.Sites.Value) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Site       = $site
            Thumbprint = $thumb
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can have `$siteThumbs` be displayed in a way that each site corresponds to its own thumbprint. Right now, the output I'm getting is this:
`Site{site 1, testing site 2, testing site 255....}`
`Thumbprint  #########`

Answer (score 0):

(1) IIS site may have 'N' number of SSL Bindings depending on use of multiple Host Names and/or Ports so to capture those you can do:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | Foreach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
     Site=$_.sites.value
     HostName=$_.Host
     Port=$_.Port
     Thumb=$_.thumbprint
  }
}
```

Bonus Section:  The following will show how to query remote servers and will pre-filter based upon only unique thumbprints while also querying HKLM:\ to assist in displaying typical cert info.

```
$ComputerName = 'Server1','Server2'
$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $MyCred -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    $SSLBindings = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | 
        Sort-Object thumbprint -unique
    $SSLBindings | Foreach-Object {
            $cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My |
                Where-Object thumbprint -Match $_.thumbprint |
                Select-Object Subject, SerialNumber, NotBefore, NotAfter
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Site = $_.sites.value
            Thumb = $_.thumbprint
            Subject = $cert.Subject
            Serial = $cert.SerialNumber
            NotBefore = $cert.NotBefore
            NotAfter = $cert.NotAfter
        }
    } 
}
$Results
```